# How do threads actually work?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

Here is a scenario

We have two threads both access same piece of code and that code has a variable, for instance

int a=200;

thread A enters and changes it's value to a=300;

then thread B access this variable , what would thread B get 200 or 300?

Comment: Depends on what "then" means. If you don't use synchronization, thread B might come along before thread A changes the value.

Comment: plus due to memory barriers, thread B may never "see" the 300 value.

Comment: @gd1: Not totally. The JLS gives at least some guidance on how threads interact with memory (and the more recent specs actually have an architecture-independent memory model).

Comment: Are you talking about about **fields** or **variables**? The answer is *completely* different depending on what you mean (and it is impossible to infer from what you say, making the reasonable assumption that your language is not precise).

Answer (score 2):

Two threads aren't guaranteed to execute in any fixed sequence; any operation in A could precede any operation in B (provided that the operations still flow sequentially within their own threads).

Therefore, without synchronization, A might change its value before or after B accesses it. If A changes it before B, then B sees 300; otherwise, B sees 200.

Comment: Or, thread B might change the first 8 bits of the value, then thread A writes the full value, then thread B writes the final 8 bits of the value, so you end up with the top 8 bits from 300 and the lower 8 bits from 200, which is 456.  Totally not an expected value.  Moral = don't trust threads to do anything predictable to shared variables without synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

The state chart diagram below describes the thread states.

[image]

- **Runnable**  — waiting for its turn to be picked for execution by the thread scheduler based on thread priorities.
- **Running** — The processor is actively executing the thread code. It runs until it becomes blocked, or voluntarily
  gives up its turn with this static method Thread.yield(). Because of context switching overhead, yield() should
  not be used very frequently.
- **Waiting** — A thread is in a blocked state while it waits for some external processing such as file I/O to finish.
- **Sleeping** — Java threads are forcibly put to sleep (suspended) with this overloaded method:
  `Thread.sleep(milliseconds), Thread.sleep(milliseconds, nanoseconds);`
- **Blocked on I/O** — Will move to runnable after I/O condition like reading bytes of data etc changes.
- **Blocked on synchronization** — Will move to Runnable when a lock is acquired.
- **Dead** — The thread is finished working.

About your example, we don't know what thread B will take 200 or 300. If u start both threads at the same time since your method will be synchronized thread B should see 200 (in case if it will be 1st or 300).

Answer (score 1):

Due to compiler optimization the threads may cache the data and first thread changes may not be seen by second thread. That is where 'volatile' is used for shared data to avoid the issues in multi-threading environment

Addendum- Well  I was talking about the visibility of variable changes across the threads, not synchronization.

Comment: @Nippey, your statement about `volatile`, in Java, is completely wrong.

Comment: @nneonneo: Classical failure called "read before post". Deleted original comment.

Answer (score 0):

if your threads access simultaneously your piece of code it will happen according to the thread priority in jvm level. We cant guaranteed which thread is going to access the code. If it is synchronized Thread B have to wait until thread A release the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the above execution depends on the consistency model.

In a sequential consistency model, the result of the execution is such that all the instructions are executed in some global order. In such case, the threadB will get a value 300.

However, modern machines use a weaker consistency model where all the synchronization (memory fence instructions) operations alone occur in a global sequential order.

If the load for threadB occurs after store for threadA has completed, threadB will get the value = 300. This is guaranteed by the cache coherence protocol. 
However, if the load instruction for threadB occurs before/alongwith the store of threadA (due to some optimization), the value for the shared variable in threadB is undefined. It will be the result of a race condition between the load of threadB and store of threadA over a bus operation.